# Cannot invoke setValue with an argument list of type (Int64, String)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've checked the answers here on SO and google and am stumped.

```
    func saveAvailableWord(word: GameWord) {
       let gw = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("GameWord", inManagedObjectContext: persistence.managedObjectContext!) as! NSManagedObject
       let rId = word.rowID
       gw.setValue(rId, forKey: "rowID") //*** Error line
}
```

The code above is for core data and simply tries to create an object. But I get

> "Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(Int64, forKey: String)'

on the marked line. rowID is defined as `@NSManaged var rowID: Int64` because it is coming from an SQLite *ROWID* column.

If I replace the rId variable with a simple number the error goes away. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)
```

expects an (optional) *object* as the first argument. Unlike `Int`, the fixed
size integer types `Int64`, `Int32`, ... are *not* automatically bridged to
`NSNumber` objects, so you have to call explicitly

```
gw.setValue(NSNumber(longLong: rID), forKey: "rowID")
```

But if `rowId` is defined as `Int64` in the managed object subclass,
then you can simply assign the property value with

```
gw.rowID = rID
```

without the need for Key-Value Coding methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had tried other casts but not NSNumber. Simply assigning the value is the way to go though. Thanks!