# Bridging arrays when the element type also needs to be bridged

Tags: swift

I've been having some fun trying to bridge an array. I'm trying to serialize an array of Int16 with NSCoder. Now, I thought that Int16 was bridged with NSNumber, and the array is bridged with NSArray, so I could bridge [Int16] to NSArray (containing NSNumber) without problem.

However, the Swift compiler has just informed me that this cast will always fail, and I've seen some other samples claiming that I will have to explicitly map the ints into an NSNumber myself instead of using bridging.

So what exactly are the rules for bridging arrays in Swift (when the array type may also need to be bridged)? This is in *both* directions since I need to deserialize back again.

Comment: The fixed-size integer types like Int16 are *not* automatically bridged to NSNumber, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437401/cannot-invoke-setvalue-with-an-argument-list-of-type-int64-string.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865202/how-can-i-get-an-nscoder-to-encode-decode-a-swift-array-of-structs (which is about encoding a [UInt64] array).

Comment: If Int16 isn't automatically bridged to NSNumber that pretty much answers the question really.